# How to use "checkinstall" with Python packages that use "setuptools"

Tags: python, linux, packaging, setuptools

On Ubuntu/Debian I use `checkinstall` package when installing packages from source

`sudo checkinstall make install`

or

`sudo checkinstall python setup.py install`

My problem is that Python packages that use `setuptools` (that modify `easy-install.pth` file) can't be installed correctly, as `checkinstall` asks to overwrite `easy-install.pth` for every new Python package that uses it.

I know I can use `pip install <package>` but dependencies coordinated by Debian packaging system would not "see" this package if not processed at least with `checkinstall` in lack of my better knowledge.

I hope my terminology is correct and I would like to know if this problem can be somehow resolved, asking myself:

- can `checkinstall` somehow work with Python package that uses `setuptools`?, or
- can Python package that uses `setuptools` be installed differently (like avoiding write to `easy-install.pth` with some switch to `python setup.py install` command or similar?

Comment: system packages (`apt-get`), stable and generally useful (`pip install --user`), unstable and specific to project (`virtualenv`).

Comment: Yes, but logically Synaptic has older versions. If I build i.e. SciPy 0.10b2 with my ATLAS build, I would like packages that depend on SciPy to use my build instead asking me to install `python-scipy 0.8`. Although SciPy does not have this issue with `setuptools`, but I use it as example

Comment: scipy is two step problem: 1. install BLAS and LAPACK (by whatever means you like) I'd go with `apt-get` root if at all possible 2. use `pip install --user` or virtualenv to install scipy. The good thing about Python you don't need to ldconfig its C extensions; import mechanism finds them if they are in `sys.path`. So your python modules installed by `apt-get` (or any other means) would use your scipy installation automatically.

Comment: OK man thanks for your input.  I don't have problems with SciPy as mentioned twice in my reply. Your suggestions does not overcome the problem in any way, so if you have some answer please post it, otherwise we can talk about this whole night.

Comment: To overcome the problem use `apt-get`, `pip install --user`, `virtualenv` as I've said i.e., don't use `checkinstall`. I don't post it as an answer because there might be some magic way to use `checkinstall` and `setuptools` together e.g., `sudo checkinstall pip install your_tarball.tar.gz`. pip might provide such options to `setuptools` that it won't write to `easy-install.pth`. You are welcome.

Comment: I've tried that before posting unfortunatally

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
checkinstall --exclude /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth
```